# Latex Bibliography

Tags: latex, pdflatex, latex-suite

I can't put the bibliography on my latex file. I write the code and the result of the compilation. I compile the main file in the following way:

```
main.tex (latexPdf) 
main.tex (bibtex) 
main.tex (latexPdf) 
main.tex (latexPdf)
```

But it always appears a question mark. How can I fix? I have searched several guides!

```
main.tex

    \documentclass{article}
    \title{Bibliographies}
    \author{VK}
    \date{\today}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    A book on game theory is \cite{book}.
    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibliography.bib}
    \end{document}

bibliography.bib

    @book{basar1995dynamic,
      title={Dynamic noncooperative game theory},
      author={Basar, Tamer and Olsder, Geert Jan and Clsder, GJ and Basar},
      volume={200},
      year={1995},
      publisher={SIAM}
    }
```

Output in this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDvD.png

Comment: Remove the `.bib` extension when you call the bibliography: `\bibliography{bibliography}`.

Comment: See [Citations not showing up in text and bibiography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43325/5764).